# Can't update Data in Database

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, symfony4

I have a problem with my symfony project.
I am creating my portfolio.
I created an administration interface to manage my projects.

However, when I want to save multiple photos from my project. None of this updates!

I am sharing some lines from my CS in the hope that you can help me.

```php
public function edit(Project $project, Request $request)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(ProjectType::class, $project);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $imagesProject = $form->get('imageProjects')->getData();
            $imageFirst = $form->get('imageFile')->getData();

            if ($imageFirst && $imagesProject) {
                foreach ($imagesProject as $imageProject) {
                    $fichier = md5(uniqid()) . '.' . $imageProject->guessExtension();

                    $imageProject->move(
                        $this->getParameter('image_directory'),
                        $fichier
                    );
                }

                $imgP = new ImageProject();
                $imgP->setFilename($fichier);
                $dateP = new \DateTime('now');
                $imgP->setUpdatedAt($dateP);
                $project->addImageProject($imgP);

                $imageFirst = $form->get('imageFile')->getData();

                $Imagefile = md5(uniqid()) . '.' . $imageFirst->guessExtension();

                try {
                    $imageFirst->move(
                        $this->getParameter('image_directory'),
                        $Imagefile
                    );
                } catch (FileException $e) {
                    dump($e);
                }

                $project->setFilename($Imagefile);
                $datePr = new \DateTime('now');
                $project->setUpdatedAt($datePr);

                $this->em->flush();
                $this->addFlash('add', 'Votre projet a été modifié');
                return $this->redirectToRoute('admin.project.index');
            } else if ($imageFirst && !$imagesProject) {
                $imageFirst = $form->get('imageFile')->getData();

                $Imagefile = md5(uniqid()) . '.' . $imageFirst->guessExtension();

                $imageFirst->move(
                    $this->getParameter('image_directory'),
                    $Imagefile
                );

                $project->setFilename($Imagefile);
                $datePr = new \DateTime('now');
                $project->setUpdatedAt($datePr);

                $this->em->flush();
                $this->addFlash('add', 'Votre projet a été modifié');
                return $this->redirectToRoute('admin.project.index');
            } else if (!$imageFirst && $imagesProject) {
                foreach ($imagesProject as $imageProject) {
                    $fichier = md5(uniqid()) . '.' . $imageProject->guessExtension();

                    $imageProject->move(
                        $this->getParameter('image_directory'),
                        $fichier
                    );
                }

                $imgP = new ImageProject();
                $imgP->setFilename($fichier);
                $dateP = new \DateTime('now');
                $imgP->setUpdatedAt($dateP);
                $project->addImageProject($imgP);

                $this->em->flush();
                $this->addFlash('add', 'Votre projet a été modifié');
                return $this->redirectToRoute('admin.project.index');
            } else {
                return $this->redirectToRoute('admin.project.index');
            }
        }
        return $this->render('admin/project/edit.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'AdminPropertyController',
            'project' => $project,
            'form' => $form->createView()

        ]);
    }
```

My Image Entity

```php
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $filename;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Project::class, inversedBy="imageProjects")
     */
    private $project;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $updated_at;

    /**
     * @var File|null
     */
    private $imageFile;
```

The goal of my system would be to be able to save several files (pictures) in order to display it on my website.
However, I can save one image but when I try to save several, my edit function does not update anything !!

Comment: `$fichier = md5(uniqid()) . '.' . $imageProject->guessExtension()` is overwritten on each loop. And then, outside, `$imgP->setFilename($fichier);` You might want to move everything related to `$fichier` and `$imgP` inside the foreach loop. Probably more, but there are too much code, I didn't read all

Comment: Do you call $em->persist(...); on newly created ImageProjects?

Comment: No i don't call this

Comment: If you don't, does your `Project` entity have a `cascade={"persist"}` OneToMany annotation property on its `$imageProjects` field ?

Comment: yes, he have this annotation